# How to parse XML by attribute values?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, nodelist

**Introduction**

I have a summarized "country.xml" file shown below that I got from a website
I need to parse this xml by its attribute names.

For example I want to have such a list:

```
Country: Germany
Population: 82521653
GDP: 3466000000000

Country: Switzerland
Population: 8417700
GDP: 659800000000
```

The problem is, that the tag names are almost the same.

**What I've got now**

```
Country: Germany
Population: Germany
GDP: Germany

Country: Switzerland
Population: Switzerland
GDP: Switzerland

Country: Austria
Population: Austria
GDP: Austria
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("country.xml");

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);

            Element element=doc.getDocumentElement();
            element.normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Country");

            for (int i=0; i<nList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nList.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element2 = (Element) node;
                    tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"\nCountry : " + getValue("string", element2)+"\n");
                    tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"Population : " + getValue("string", element2)+"\n");
                    tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"GDP : " + getValue("string", element2)+"\n");
                    tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"-----------------------");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
        NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
        Node node = nodeList.item(0);
        return node.getNodeValue();
    }
}
```

*Country.xml*

```
<Country>
    <string name="CountryName">Germany</string>
    <string name="Population">82521653</string>
    <null name="Area">357385</null>
    <null name="GDP">3466000000000</null>
</Country>
<Country>
    <string name="CountryName">Switzerland</string>
    <string name="Population">8417700</string>
    <null name="Area">41285</null>
    <null name="GDP">659800000000</null>
</Country>
<Country>
    <string name="CountryName">Austria</string>
    <string name="Population">8772865</string>
    <null name="Area">83878</null>
    <null name="GDP">386700000000</null>
</Country>
```

**Question**

How can I get the values by its attribute names?

What I tried is:

```
tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"\nCountry : " + getValue("string name=\"CountryName\"", element2)+"\n");
```

But this gives me an empty string back.

Comment: you use the same tag ("String") in all your calls of getValue(). Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes I think so. But the tag ("String") is also in a few rows in the xml file. When I change the value of my calls to "string name=\"CountryName\"" it will give me an empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can't get the textContent of an element by the attribute name directley.

But you can do it like this:

Call getValue for each country, as you did, but give it the correct tag names (like "CountryCode").
In getValue() you first get a list of the child nodes for the Country element.
Then you get the attribute name for each child node and compare it with the tag name. If its equal, you return the textContent of the element.

Have a look here, it works like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("country.xml");

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);

            Element element=doc.getDocumentElement();
            element.normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Country");

            for (int i=0; i<nList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nList.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element2 = (Element) node;
                    tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"\nCountry : " + getValue("CountryName", element2)+"\n");
                    tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"Population : " + getValue("Population", element2)+"\n");
                    tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"GDP : " + getValue("GDP", element2)+"\n");
                    tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"-----------------------");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
        NodeList childNodes = element.getChildNodes();
        for (int i=0 ; i<childNodes.getLength() ; i++) {
            if (childNodes.item(i).hasAttributes()) {
                String attributeName = childNodes.item(i).getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                if (attributeName.equals(tag)) {
                    return childNodes.item(i).getTextContent();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```